# Loss of information while structure casting

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, casting

I'm passing a struct by typecasting it as an integer.
On the output, printBook(), I'm re-acquiring the socket, by typecasting the typed passed integer.

Expected output:-

```
Book id : 11
Book no of copies : 2
Book id : 12
Book no of copies : 10
```

Actual Output

```
Book id : 11
Book no of copies : 0
Book id : 12
Book no of copies : 0
```

Why am I losing partial data?
Here's the snippet.

```
#define UINT16 int

typedef  unsigned int UINT32;
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// this replicates my new Data structure
typedef struct books
{
   UINT16   book_id;
   UINT16   book_no_of_copies;
   books() : book_id(0), book_no_of_copies(0) {}
} BOOKS;

void printBook( UINT32 book );

int main( )
{
    BOOKS Book1;        // Declare Book1 of type BOOKS
    BOOKS Book2;        // Declare Book2 of type BOOKS

    // book 1 specification
    Book1.book_id = 11; // initialization
    Book1.book_no_of_copies = 2;

    // book 2 specification
    Book2.book_id = 12; // initialization
    Book2.book_no_of_copies = 10;

    // pass struct as integer
    // Print Book1 info
    printBook( *(UINT32 *)&Book1 );

    // Print Book2 info
    printBook( *(UINT32 *)&Book2 );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void printBook( UINT32 book )
{
    // re-convert integer to struct
    BOOKS myBook = *(BOOKS *)& book;
    cout << "Book id : " << myBook.book_id <<endl;
    cout << "Book no of copies : " << myBook.book_no_of_copies <<endl;
}
```

Comment: `#define UINT16 int`, `typedef  unsigned int UINT32;` what? int and unsigned int have different sizes?

Comment: On my ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit) os, "sizeof(int)" reports 4 bytes, the same as "sizeof(uint32_t)" ,  Thus your "#define UINT16 int" would not be what you expected on some os's.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `*(UINT32 *)&Book1` is *undefined* in C++. This is because the types are *unrelated*. It would be particularly fragile on a 64 bit platform where pointers are larger than 32 bit.

You *could* get away with a cast to and from `void*`, but that's not really how things ought to be done in C++.

Why not move `printBook` *inside* the `books` `struct`? You can do that in C++: C++ `struct`s can accommodate member *functions* as well as member *data*. (And the C-style `typedef` idiom around your `struct` is not needed in C++).

Lastly, `#define UINT16 int` followed by `typedef unsigned int UINT32;` is just bizarre. Consider using the standard fixed sizes (e.g. `std::uint32_t`) if your compiler supports it.

Comment: what's the right way to do such a cast in C++ then?
I cannot move the printBook() inside the struct because it changes the design.

Comment: Preferably pass a `books*`, but failing that, use a `void*` but only if you're not able to "change the design".

Comment: @Bathasheba: too bad, i can't design change the definition of `printBook(UINT32 book)` either. It has to accept an integer variable, and not a pointer to it.

Comment: @Bathasheba: and yeah, it works wonders with `books*`, unfortunately can't use it in final product